# AT Command to change frame size gives ERROR

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim900

I'm using a SIM900A GSM Shield to communicate between an arduino due and an API. 
I currently using it's default values in the multiplexer of GSM Shield. But now I'm in need of changing it's frame size to 255. When I check the current frame size, it gives following response which indicates the frame size as 127.

```
CMUX Read:AT+CMUX?

+CMUX: 0,0,5,127,10,3,30,10,2
OK
```

Then I used following AT command to change it to 255. But it gives an ERROR.

```
sim900_send_cmd("AT+CMUX=0[,0[,1[,255[,10[,3[,30[,10[,2]]]]]]]]\r\n");

CMUX Read:AT+CMUX=0[,0[,5[,255[,10[,3[,30[,10[,2]]]]]]]] 
ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong here ? am I missing a step ? Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You should not terminate the AT command line with `\r\n`, only just `\r` is valid. Do yourself a favour and read all of chapter 5 in [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en), that will teach you a lot about basic AT command handling.

Comment: I didnt know that, thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in AT commands, but I bet you don't need all the brackets in yours. Brackets are used to indicate parameters which could be omitted. So your command should look like this:

```
CMUX Read:AT+CMUX=0,0,5,255,10,3,30,10,2
```

Maybe even a shoter version will work:

```
CMUX Read:AT+CMUX=0,0,5,255
```